# TypeError when calling member or constructor from @types/sjcl in tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I am trying to extend one project. I've added sjcl and @types/sjcl. I can successfully define types e.g.

```
var x = sjcl.BigNumber | undefined
private _secret: sjcl.SjclEcdsaSecretKey
```

But when I do:

```
sjcl.ecc.curves.k256
```

or

```
new sjcl.bn(1)
```

The test run complains as follows:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'curves' of undefined

or

> TypeError: sjcl.bn is not a constructor

This happens while testing. This is the test command:

```
nyc mocha --require ts-node/register --require source-map-support/register --full-trace --timeout 40000 ./test/**/**.spec.ts
```

I am new to TypeScript/npm/javascript having a background in other languages.
Much thanks for any help.

Comment: `var` is used for define variable not type, `type` is; and in normal js expression '|'  is bitwise OR, are you sure you're doing it the right way?

Comment: This isn't TypeScript related

Comment: @Austaras This part actually works ;). Consider:
a)`var bn: sjcl.BigNumber | undefined`
b) `var bnn = new sjcl.bn(1)`

It fails on b.

Comment: @AluanHaddad it uses @types/sjcl wrapper and this is how it refers to all the calls ... it's some how related to something. I am more interested in the process of pin-pointing the issue and getting it solved.

Comment: It's not typescript related because it's a runtime error

Comment: @AluanHaddad I've seen some issues to add imports because type resolution did not work at runtime. Nevertheless I use the wrappers so its at least `@Type/sjcl` related. How to debug such error especially in unit tests ;)

Comment: Also I see some other issues saying it may be that the typings are written for an older version. I already tried sjcl one version down (1.0.7) from around the time the typigns were writte. Will have to investigate more.

Comment: So it seams @types/sjcl is for version 1.0.1 of sjcl. However downgrading did not help :(.

Comment: Update: So it seems that normally you download the scripts for sjcl and compile them e.g.
`$ git clone https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl.git
$ cd sjcl
$ ./configure # Requests for extensions go here, e.g. --with-ecc --with-srp
$ make sjcl.js
$ make test  # If any of the tests fail, beware.`

The postinstall however seems to not work when used in packages.js ... So what is the approach in NPM to do such configuration?